# Using pThread is worse than Sequential

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads, matrix-multiplication

Using pthread library, I've had written some code for matrix multiplication.

AFAIK, the program using thread would be much faster than program without using thread. But, unlike my expectation... the outcome(Elapsed time) is totally reversed, the program not using thread is much faster than thread program. What happened.. I couldn't find why this is happened.

The Execution time below..

```
Time ( # of thread: 4 )

0.000451 sec

Time ( no thread )

0.000002 sec
```

I've coded this two version in one file(.c)

> **but always pThread is worse than sequential**

.

1. Serial version ( no using thread )

   ```
   void serial_multi()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
           for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
               for(int k = 0; k < MAX; k++)
                   _matC[i][j] += matA[i][k] * matB[k][j];
   }
   ```
2. Using Thread ( # of thread : 4 )

   ```
    int step_i = 0;
    void* multi(void* arg)
    {
       int core = step_i++;
       // each thread computes 1/4th of matrix multiplication
       for (int i = core * MAX / 4; i < (core + 1) * MAX/4; i++)
           for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
               for(int k = 0; k < MAX; k++)
                   matC[i][j] += matA[i][k] * matB[k][j];
       return NULL; 
    }
   ```
3. main function

   ```
    int main()
   {
    printf("PID: %d\n",getpid());
    // generating random values in matA and matB
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++){
            matA[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            matB[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    //cout << endl << "Matrix A" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
            printf("%d ",matA[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }


    //cout << endl << "Matrix B" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
            printf("%d ",matB[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    // declaring 4 threads
    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREAD];

    // creating 4 threads, each evaluating its own part
        // Time Estimation
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++){

        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, multi, NULL);
    }

    // joining and waiting for all threads to complete
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    clock_t end = clock();
    printf("Time: %lf\n", (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    // displaying the result matrix
    //cout << endl << "Multiplication of A and B" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
            printf("%d ",matC[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }



    return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Your serial program runs faster than the overhead the threads impose.

Comment: What is the value of `MAX`? 2 microseconds is too small to expect an improvement, especially if you are creating threads, not reusing threads in a pool.

Comment: That code is also not thread safe. There is no atomic-protection of `step_i`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, it does. using threads is not proper in this problem?

Comment: @KenY-N Actually the value of MAX is number of thread I'll use. So in order to check the thread is faster, I change the value of MAX greater but Sequential one is still fast.

Comment: @WhozCraig yep, it needs kinds of critical-section thanks.

Comment: Problem solved, time measurement with clock() is not suitable for parallel program.(it sums all elapsed time of each thread) So I used gettimeofday() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the threaded program runs slower because of two items.

1. the threading takes extra time for context switches
2. the creation/destruction of a thread takes time

Those two items are the main 'extra' time takers.

Also, you should note that this program is CPU bound, not I/O bound.  A I/O bound program would benefit from threading, but; a CPU bound program is (significantly) delayed due to all the context switching, the creation of the threads, and the destruction of the threads.

Note:  the program could easily be made quicker via the use of a 'thread pool'.

Comment: So you mean, this program would be slow at short-size of matrix multiplication(but in big-size of matrix, it is powerful) because of cpu bounded. But in I/O bounded, like socket programming this could be effective because not obstructed by same CPU. Am I right?

Comment: @HenryKIM,  Not really,  To make the matrix larger would not help the program to be faster.

Comment: Ah I meant to say, compared to Sequential program. Thanks for your reply :)